# Sympy Inverse Fourier Transform has a wrong answer

Tags: python, signals, sympy

`sympy` is a very famous library, I don't think it can make such low-level mistakes. So I think I didn't find which parameters.But..ehm..I have looked for the documentation of official, still have no result.

[image]

I want to know why and how to get the correct answer. I try it in Matlab, and after the transformation, the inverse transformation is the same as the original. (The main problem is without the Abs.)

VERY THANKS

Comment: Many thanks for correcting mistakes, I'm new here.

Comment: So is the problems is that `inverse_fourier_transform(fourier_transform(exp(-2*abs(t),t,k),k,t)` gives `exp(-2*t)` with the `t` instead of `Abs(t)`?

Comment: Yes,this is exactly my problem